# How do I group items by initial letter with liquid?

Tags: liquid

I have an object with multiple brand names. However I would like to group them by initial letter.
Ex:
A --
Amazon,
Apple.
B --
Beats,
Budweiser,
Burguer king.
...

```
{% for brand in ComponentData.Brands %}
     {{ brand.Name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
{% assign alphabet = "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z" %}
{% assign alphabet = alphabet | split:',' %}
{% for letter in alphabet %}
    -{{ letter }}   
    {% for brand in ComponentData.Brands %}
        {% assign firstletter = brand.Name | truncate: 1, '' %}
        {% comment %} or use: {% assign firstletter = brand.Name | slice: 0 %} {% endcomment %}
        {% if letter == firstletter %}
            --{{brand.Name}}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}    
{% endfor %}
```